# Join three rows if the same value in one column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

There is a Postgres database and the table has three columns. The data structure is in external system so I can not modify it.

Every object is represented by three rows (identified by column element_id - rows with the same value in this column represents the same object), for example:

```
key     value            element_id
-----------------------------------
status  active           1
name    exampleNameAAA   1
city    exampleCityAAA   1
status  inactive         2
name    exampleNameBBB   2
city    exampleCityBBB   2
status  inactive         3
name    exampleNameCCC   3
city    exampleCityCCC   3
```

I want to get all values  describing every objects (name, status and city).

For this example the output should be like:

```
exampleNameAAA   | active    | exampleCityAAA
exampleNameBBB   | inactive  | exampleCityBBB
exampleNameCCC   | inactive  | exampleCityCCC
```

I know how to join two rows:

```
select a.value as name,
       b.value as status
from the_table a 
  join the_table b 
    on a.element_id = b.element_id 
   and b."key" = 'status'
where a."key" = 'name';
```

How is it possible to join three columns?

Comment: Simply add another JOIN. Keep the one and only WHERE at the end.

Comment: @jarlh could you post the example?

Comment: SELECT t1.c1, t2.cx ... FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ... JOIN t3 ON ... WHERE...

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0051f0dd2f8c7d5b25298fd34c2d43f)**

```
select a.value as name,
       b.value as status,c.value as city
from t1 a 
  join t1 b 
    on a.element_id = b.element_id and b."keys" = 'status'
    join t1 c on a.element_id = c.element_id and c."keys" = 'city'
where a."keys" = 'name';
```

OUTPUT

```
name            status      city
exampleNameAAA  active      exampleCityAAA
exampleNameBBB  inactive    exampleCityBBB
exampleNameCCC  inactive    exampleCityCCC
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply add another join for each value you need (this is one of the big disadvantages of the [EAV (anti) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) you are using:

```
select a.value as name,
       b.value as status, 
       c.value as city
from the_table a 
  join the_table b on a.element_id = b.element_id and b."key" = 'status'
  join the_table c on a.element_id = c.element_id and c."key" = 'city'
where a."key" = 'name';
```

---

Another option is to aggregate all key/value pairs for an element into a JSON then you can easily access each one without additional joins:

```
select t.element_id, 
       t.obj ->> 'city' as city, 
       t.obj ->> 'status' as status,
       t.obj ->> 'name' as name
from (
  select e.element_id, jsonb_object_agg("key", value) as obj
  from element e
  group by e.element_id
) t;
```

If the table is really big this might be a lot slower than the join version due to the aggregation step. If you limit the query to only some elements (e.g.  by adding a `where element_id = 1` or `where element_id in (1,2,3)`) then this should be quite fast.

It has the advantage that you always have all key/value pairs for each element_id available regardless on what you do. The inner select could be put into a view, to make things easier.

Online example: https://rextester.com/MSZOWU37182

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to PIVOT

One way to do that is via conditional aggregation.

```
select 
 -- t.element_id,
 max(case when t.key = 'name' then t.value end) as name,
 max(case when t.key = 'status' then t.value end) as status,
 max(case when t.key = 'city' then t.value end) as city
from the_table t
group by t.element_id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=092f95e8a78775162f131982d08c2a00)*

Or use crosstab:

```
select 
-- element_id,
name, 
status, 
city
from crosstab (
   'select t.element_id, t.key, t.value 
   from the_table t'
) as ct (element_id int, name varchar(30), status varchar(30), city varchar(30));
```

But if you do like those joins, here's a way

```
select 
-- el.element_id,
nm.value as name,
st.value as status,
ci.value as city
from 
(
  select distinct t.element_id 
  from the_table t
  where t.key in ('name','status','city')
) as el
left join the_table as nm on (nm.element_id = el.element_id and nm.key = 'name')
left join the_table as st on (st.element_id = el.element_id and st.key = 'status')
left join the_table as ci on (ci.element_id = el.element_id and ci.key = 'city');
```